# Returning a null value in Haskell without constricting Polymorphism

Tags: haskell

I'm following "Real World Haskell", and am going through chapter 2, where the exercise is to create a "lastButOne" function which returns the second to last value in the list. My original code was:

```
lastButOne xs =     if null (tail (tail xs))
                    then head xs
                    else lastButOne (tail xs)
```

Which works fine unless I give it a list with only 1 or 2 items. So I modified it to this:

```
lastButOne xs = if null xs || null (tail xs)
                then head xs
                else
                        if null (tail (tail xs))
                        then head xs
                        else lastButOne (tail xs)
```

Which checks if it only has 1 or 2 items, but then fails if it only has 1 item because of the call to head. My problem is that I can't think of anything else to return other than "head xs", ideally I want it to return null or something like that, but I can't find a "null" that allows the function to still be polymorphic.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for a `Maybe` type:

```
lastButOne :: [a] -> Maybe a
lastButOne [x,_] = Just x
lastButOne (_:y:ys) = lastButOne (y:ys)
lastButOne _ = Nothing
```

Answer (score 10):

> [I]deally I want it to return null or something like that, but I can't find a "null" that allows the function to still be polymorphic.

There are a number of answers already in posted on how to make this work, so instead let me answer the more fundamental question of "Why isn't there a 'null'?"

This is part of the philosophy of the type-checker in Haskell. most languages include some form of a special value that signals an error or lack of data. Examples include `0`,`-1` `""` (the empty string) JavaScripts `null` or Ruby's `nil`.  The problem is that this creates a whole class of potential bugs wherein the calling function only deals with "good" values and the program crashes or worse corrupts data when a *special* value is returned.  There is also the issue of the special value being intended as a regular value -- that is `0` actually being a number and not a failure state.

In your problem, the question could be framed, "Would the function that calls `lastButOne` know what to do with `null`?"

The problem of not having a valid answer for certain otherwise well-formed inputs is a very common one in Haskell and has two typical solutions.  The first is taken from Erlang: Fail quickly and cleanly.  Under this solution it is the responsibility of the caller to ensure that the data is "good." If it is not the program dies with an error (or the exception is caught, but this is more difficult in Haskell then other languages) This is the solution used by most list functions e.g. `head`, `tail`, etc...

The other solution is to explicitly state that the function may fail to produce good data.  The `Maybe a` type is the simplest of these solutions.  It allows you to return a value `Nothing` that works much like the `null` you are looking for.  But there is a cost to this.  Your function's type signature becomes `lastButOne :: [a] -> Maybe a`.  Now every calling function must take not an `a` but a `Maybe a`, and before it can get its answer, it must tell Haskell what it is going to do if the answer is `Nothing`.

Comment: Very well put. To the OP, you will also see `Maybe` used a whole lot more as you work your way through RWH. Then when you go back to Java or whatever, you'll be terrified because *every single variable in your program* could turn out to be null if you aren't careful.

Answer (score 5):

Well, this depends on how much error-checking you actually want to do.

I suspect that, given this is only in Chapter 2, you are probably meant to ignore this edge case. Haskell itself throws an exception:

```
Prelude> head []
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

The alternative, if this is a case that you will have to deal with a lot, would be to change the return type of `lastButOne` to `Maybe a` and return `Just (head xs)` when it works, and `Nothing` when it fails. But this means that you would always have deal with living inside the  `Maybe` [monad](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad), which may not be ideal (as you would have to "unwrap" the `Just` value to use it).

Comment: Actually we can escape from `Maybe`.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe: I think he meant via good-old pattern matching: `case m of { Just x -> ... ; Nothing -> ... }` Having to unwrap the Just is precisely the point of having a Maybe type since you can have the type system protect you from NullPtrExceptions.

Comment: But the point is that some errors really are sometimes best left as errors. There's a reason the prelude doesn't have `head::[a]->Maybe a`.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe I know many Haskellers that would prefer `head` and others of its ilk to return a `Maybe` value.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use pattern matching to handle the case where you have only 1 or 2 elements?
Something like:

```
lastButOne :: [a] -> Maybe a
lastButOne [x,y] = Just x
lastButOne (x:y:t) = lastButOne (y:t)
lastButOne  _ = Nothing
```

Comment: `null` is not the traditional "null" value - its a function to test if a list is empty. I don't think this code compiles...

Answer (score 0):

An example of "extended error handling" mentioned by @Andrew Jaffe could be:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-} module Main where

import Control.Monad.Error

lastButOne :: MonadError String m => [a] -> m a
lastButOne (_ : y : []) = return y 
lastButOne (_ : t) = lastButOne
lastButOne _ = throwError "Error in lastButOne"
```

In this case, it is possible to return `Either` type: `Right x` in case of success and `Left "Error in lastButOne"` in case of failure, but many other instances of `MonadError String m` are possible.

Also read [8 ways to report errors in Haskell](http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2007/03/10/haskell-8-ways-to-report-errors) for more possibilities.